# How to add Z axis BarGraph using Core Plot in Iphone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-plot

I have read the tutorials about making 2D BarGraph using Core Plot in iPhone.
I want to add Z-axis to it to make it 3D.

**EDIT :**
I searched but I could not find great solution. I want to show something like figure below.

[image]

Guide me regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True 3D is not supported in Core Plot right now. The best you'll be able to do is use gradient or image fills on the various parts of the graph to simulate a 3D appearance.